# Visualforce lookup to Account

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I am developing a page which will allow a user to select an Account and it will use that Id to construct a URL. I have no objects in my org with a lookup field to Account, and therefore I cannot use `<apex:inputField>`. Is there a simple way to do this? I don't want to create a field on any object because I cannot be sure that a user will have correct permissions for that object. 
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

explicitly specifying without sharing also will help give access to all objects

Comment: This did not work. With/without sharing only refers to sharing rules.